# Transform raw forecasts into orthogonal forecasts

Tags: correlation, finance-mathematics, covariance-matrix, forecasting

I am trying to combine multiple forecasts on each of N assets in line with Grinold and Kahn's methodology, taken from *Active Portfolio Management, 2nd ed.* On p.311, they suggest transforming the raw forecasts **g** into a set of uncorrelated (orthogonal) forecasts **y**. This is done as follows:
\begin{align*}
Var\{g\} = H^T\cdot H\\
y \equiv (H^T)^{-1}\cdot[g-E\{g\}]
\end{align*}
Can someone please explain what the matrix H is and what process is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have access to this book but I suppose the decomposition is the cholesky decomposition (if you use R, simply generate it with

```
chol(cov(g))
```

where g is a matrix with forecasts.
What the transformation is doing are essentially two steps:
1. You replace the forecasts g with the normalized forecasts g-E(g). This can be done by demeaning the matrix (R: demean)
2. Your normalize the variaton by 'dividing' with the part of the cholesky decompostion. Recall: In the univariate case the part $(H^T)^{-1}$ would correspond to the standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks - i'm working in Python so `chol = np.linalg.cholesky(np.cov(old_signals, rowvar = False))
        new_signals =np.linalg.inv(chol)*old_signals`